# Coding a Bivariate Barplot with a non-numerical variable

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot, graph

I am trying to create a stacked or grouped barplot graph for the **ScoreRecent** and **Facility_Type_Description** within the following dataset I have (this is only a small snapshot of what it looks like)
[image]

Each variable graphed alone looks like this:
[image]
[image]

Both variables are listed as "numeric".
I have begun with:

```
 Biv.plot <- as.matrix(data.frame(FoodFacilityInspections$ScoreRecent, FoodFacilityInspections$Facility_Type_Description))
colnames(Biv.plot) <- c("Facility Scores", "Facility Types")
Biv.plot
```

I have attempted:

```
barplot(Biv.plot)
```

it ended up looking like this [image]

I then tried ggplot:

```
ggplot(Biv.plot, aes(x = Facility Types, fill = Facility Scores)) + geom_bar(position = "fill") + labs( y = "Proportion")
```

> > ggplot(Biv.plot, aes(x = Facility Types, fill = Facility Scores)) + geom_bar(position = "fill") + labs( y = "Proportion")
> > Error: unexpected symbol in "ggplot(Biv.plot, aes(x = Facility Types"

I am very new to R and don't really know how to continue from this point.
Ideally, I would like it to look like either of these:
[image]
[image]

Comment: The first of you plots is a grouped barplot, the second is a stacked bar plot. Do soime searching. There must be hundreds of worked examples on DO of these two plotting strategies. There will not be many people that want to offer solutions because you pasted your data in as an image. That is a "cardinal sin" for SO questions.

Comment: I used the images to visually show how my data is turning out and what I am hoping to achieve. I thought that would be helpful in explaining where I am trying to get to. I don't think I am at a level yet on here yet where I can share my data, but I appreciate you pointing that out as I am fairly new to the platform.

Comment: ... one issue with your code is that your column names contain spaces. In that case you have to wrap them in backticks: `ggplot(Biv.plot, aes(x = \`Facility Types\`, fill = \`Facility Scores\`)) + ...`